# Have options menu open class when you press it?

Tags: android, eclipse

What I have is that there is a menu option that says number guessing game and when it is pressed then it offers up a toast saying a word. What I want it to do is that so when it is pressed then it will open a class that exists within the project. This project is called InputEvent.java if that is relevant. How would I go about doing this? This is the code I have currently to open the menu and display the toast when it is pressed:

```
 //******** THE MENUS ***********//
 //Create the OPTIONS menu on start up 
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater(); //To inflate the xml
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.walk_options_menu,menu); //Inflate the options 
    return true;
}
//Respond to item selected on OPTIONS MENU 
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle item selection
      switch (item.getItemId()) {

      case R.id.NumGame:
            Toast.makeText(this, "Twitter", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            return true;  
      default    
      :
          return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

Comment: what does "opening a class" mean exactly ?

Comment: I think it's the name of an activity within eclipse.

Comment: sorry, you lost me there

Comment: What I want to do is open a different activity when I press a menu option which is a separate one.

Comment: So the current one is say just a list of items but what I want it to do when pressed is go to a seperate item that is say a number guessing game

Comment: so `InputEvent` is an `Activity` ?

Comment: Yes it's the activity that I want to open.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
// Handle item selection
    switch (item.getItemId()) {

        case R.id.NumGame:
             //Toast.makeText(this, "Twitter", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
             Intent i = new Intent(this, InputEvent.class);
             startActivity(i);
             return true;  
        default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

Comment: This works thanks I forgot to add it as an application.